# Python/IronPython- how to return value of specific attribute of class when only class object referenced?

Tags: python, class, attributes, default, ironpython

Ok, just trying to get into Python, specifically, I'm using the benefit of on-the-fly calculations from within a C# app calling the IronPython engine. I pass in to IP a list of C# objects of class C, and am going to do a bunch of calculations. There's a legacy (SQL) reference to a certain member of the class, call it CURRENTAMOUNT. There are other values of attributes that will be referenced in the calculations but I was wondering if there's a way to automatically return the value of CURRENTAMOUNT if only the object is referenced.

C# Class MyNumbersClass

```
public class MyNumbersClass
{
   decimal SomeVal_A;
   decimal SomeVal_B;
   decimal CurrentAmount;
}
```

... gather a List called NumbersList...

... instantiate IronPython engine E
... set scope S
... set IP list PNumbers to C# list NumbersList

```
S.SetVariable(PNumbers, NumbersList)
```

So now, a simple calculation in IronPython(IP) is to calculate the following:

```
PNumbers[10].CurrentAmount = PNumbers[0].SomeVal_A * (PNumbers[2].SomeVal_B / DaysInWeek) - PNumbers[5].CurrentAmount
```

How can I re-write this so CurrentAmount is the default attribute to set and get when none specified?
I.e., PNumbers[10] = PNumbers[0].SomeVal_A * (PNumbers[2].SomeVal_B / DaysInWeek) - PNumbers[5]

I have way over-simplified the example as all I can say is that the existing legacy attributes of the passed in C# class are VERY long and wordy, and CurrentAmount is the default attribute set and/or referenced and it is HALF of the size of the legacy name for the commonly used attribute.

I realize as I type this that there might be unintended consequences of what I'm asking - i.e., when I really DO want to just reference the object of the class as a whole.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It you're always dealing with lists of items, you could create a class in C# that wraps the list and implements `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` (basically overloading the `[]` operator) to refer to `CurrentAmmount`. You'll lose the ability to completely replace an element of that list from Python, but that might not matter in your case.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, once given to IP, all I'm doing is accessing attributes of each item in the lists, doing some calcs on them and plugging the result back into the CurrentAmount attribute.